# Spring boot + JDBCTemplate or Hibernate: Write the same row in two schemas, while preserving transactionality

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot REST service that needs to insert the same row into two identical schemas. The operation should be transactional across schemas.

The schemas are dynamically determined based on some request parameters. Schemas can also be generated on the fly, so I cannot preconfigure all the datasources. Neither can I have entities per schema or Spring repos per schema.

What I have tried and worked:

- used JDBCTemplate to execute the same Native Query twice, once for each schema, all included in a @Transactional method:

{

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private final String SQL_INSERT_PERSON_SCHEMA_1 = "insert into SCHEMA1.PERSON(id, name, age) values(?,?,?)";
private final String SQL_INSERT_PERSON_SCHEMA_2 = "insert into SCHEMA2.PERSON(id, name, age) values(?,?,?)";

@Transactional
public void createPerson(Person person) {
    jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_INSERT_PERSON_SCHEMA_1, person.id, person.name, person.age);
    jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_INSERT_PERSON_SCHEMA_2, person.id, person.name, person.age);
 ...
}
```

}

- my worry here is the amount of boilerplate code that we will generate and that we will mix both hibernate (for read operations) and JdbcTemplate

What I have tried and did not work:

- a Transactional method that calls a Spring Data Repo create() method on each schema. Here I have figured out that the TransactionManager and the EntityManagerHolder is shared on both calls, so the write is executed twice in the same schema.

What I would like to achieve ideally: manage all this without the need of JDBC template or some more fancy mechanism that would bring significant overhead (2-phase-commit?)

Are there othere options or things to consider when trying to solve this issue?